# SVN checkout error behind proxy

Tags: svn

I'm trying to checkout from back40computing

> svn checkout http://back40computing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ back40computing-read-only

but svn is giving me following error

> svn: OPTIONS of 'http://back40computing.googlecode.com/svn/trunk': could not connect to server (http://back40computing.googlecode.com)

I'm behind proxy. What settings should I do in /etc/subversion/servers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set the proxy server and port settings so that command line SVN can access the external world form the proxy.

```
[global]
http-proxy-host = myproxy.us.com
http-proxy-port = 8080
```

Uncomment and Change other lines as required.

Source: [HTTP Proxy for SVN](http://vikashazrati.wordpress.com/2009/01/25/http-proxy-sv/)

Hope it helps.